# Can a Celestial body have a mountain rise all the way to Synchronous Orbit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, material-science, planets, estimation

On Earth, the tallest mountain is [Mauna Loa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauna_loa). In the solar system, to date, the tallest mountain is [Mons Olympus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mons_Olympus). Both fall far short of [GSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geosynchronous_orbit).

Mars gravity is 0.376 of Earth gravity. If Mauna Loa were on Mars it would have an altitude of ~80000 ft. If Mons Olympus were on Earth it would similarly be no more than ~27000 ft. Yet these are almost comparable altitudes.

Is it possible for a mountain to rise as high as GSO? Are all known tallest peaks on planets in the Solar System similarly limited?

Comment: on planets? I doubt that. The requirement for a planet is that it be roughly spherical. For asteroids? Chances are that the entire geosynchronous orbit lies way below the surface.

Comment: any celestial body in the solar system (+: I'll make the correction

Comment: For other celestial bodies it wouldn't be *geo*-synchronous orbits.

Comment: @JanDvorak: How about making that an answer?

Comment: ah, no, I take the second part back. I'll write out why

Comment: Don't synchronous orbits have to be circular? It seems like the biggest problem here is whether the mountain is too large (and thus, the celestial body as a whole too oblate) for circular orbits to exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible for an object in the solar system to have a bulge large enough to create weightlessness on the top of that bulge?

Absolutely. Heck, you don't even need a bulge. A perfectly sperical object of mass $M$ and radius $R$ revolving around its axis in a period $t$ would have zero gravitational acceleration at its equator if the gravitational acceleration matches the centripetal acceleration:

$$\frac{G M}{R^2} = \frac{(2 \pi R)^2}{R t^2}$$

Defining the density $\rho = \frac{4 \pi M}{3 R^3}$, this equatorial weightlessness condition can be written:

$$G \rho t^2 = 3 \pi$$

A spinning spherical grain / boulder / asteroid with density $\rho = 6 \ 10^3 kg/m^3$ revolving around its axis roughly every 1.5 hrs ($5 \ 10^3 \ s$) would do.

Note that the size of the object doesn't enter the picture. The rotational speed and mass density is all that matters. For non-spherical (disc-shaped) objects the above equation still gives a good approximation if you substitute for $\rho$ the object's mass divided by the volume of the smallest sphere enclosing the object.

Comment: An object rotating at that speed wouldn't be spherical, however.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Why not? Make the grain as small as you want.

Comment: Even Earth is flat at the poles. This will be more pronounced the faster you go. At one point you even lose rotational symmetry. I'll try to find the article

Comment: @JanDvora - Key elements of the answer are rotational speed and mass density of the object. Everything else is 2nd order effects.  If you insist on including non-spherical shapes, just substitute the mass divided by the smallest spherical volume enclosing the mass for the mass density $\rho$.

Comment: Corrected a calculation error. Nothing substantial, just a factor $10^8$ ;)

Comment: +1. Minor terminological quibble: you equate a force with a force, or an acceleration with an acceleration, but not an acceleration with a force. :)